Rational way of handling 0s and ties in Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test in the background of my context
In the background of the discussion  How to deal with ties when conducting Wilcoxon signed rank test?, I have the following 2 follow up questions:
I have 52 pre and post scores with ties and 0's so I used coin package with ties_method = "midrank" and its working perfectly without giving me any warnings. Conceptually speaking is using midrank a good solution?
If you dependent variable is ordinal with 1-4 possible values and you are using it as an interval variable, it's very likely that you will get many ties. Given the scenario, would your ties be justified in considering the data having no differences between pre and post.
